Whirlpool Quiet Partner II dishwasher won't start
The Normal light on the front panel has been blinking continuously for about 3 years. I flipped the circuit breaker for the unit for 5 min. to no avail. I pressed Heated Dry, Normal, Heated Dry, Normal to run Diagnostics, but nothing apparently happened. Is it worth investing in a new control panel and touchpad? The unit dates from 2010, but I don't believe we have run it more than 500 times total between then and 2021.
Addendum: My wife tried pressing Cancel. Now the Normal and Cancel lights are both blinking. Still won't start. I'm leaning toward replacing the whole unit, rather than just the control panel and touchpad, as I fear that might not fix it. Any advice as to what I might try?
I flipped the breaker for the DW again. Now only the Normal light is flashing.

What does the owner's manual say about the meaning of blinking light patterns?

A sinkfull of hot water and dish soap never ever blinked at someone.  Compare cost of control board to a dishwasher, but it might not be the control board either.

The user manual addresses only the Clean light flashing. In that case it says to call for service. I've been using the hot water and dish soap method since 2021, but my wife says she wants a functioning DW in addition to me.

You're considering spending $unknown for a new control board, which may fix the problem. Even if it works, you'll then have a 14-year-old-machine which might develop other maladies because of its age. The alternative is to spend something >$unknown for a new machine, which will fix the problem. Your choice...'tho the latter may be better for your domestic relationship.

Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too, particularly since no one has suggested a likely solution other than the control panel.
